# ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString for Apache Kafka Mongodb connector

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka

I am configuring a Kafka Mongodb sink connector on my Windows machine.

My connect-standalone.properties file has

`plugin.path=E:/Tools/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/plugins`

My MongoSinkConnector.properties file has

```
name=mongo-sink
topics=first_topic
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
key.ignore=true

# Specific global MongoDB Sink Connector configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017,mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
database=test_kafka
collection=transactions
max.num.retries=3
retries.defer.timeout=5000
type.name=kafka-connect
```

In the **E:/Tools/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/plugins** folder I have **mongo-kafka-connect-1.0.1.jar** file.

Command

`bin\windows\connect-standalone config\connect-standalone.properties config\MongoSinkConnector.properties`

The error I get is

```
[2020-03-23 04:04:12,376] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkConfig.createConfigDef(MongoSinkConfig.java:140)
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkConfig.<clinit>(MongoSinkConfig.java:78)
        at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector.config(MongoSinkConnector.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.Connector.validate(Connector.java:129)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:313)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:194)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.ConnectionString
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Which other jar files should I place in the plugins folder and/or config changes do I have to make?

UPDATE 1
I have placed mongodb-driver-core-4.0.1 and bson-4.0.1 jar files also in the plugins folder, but have the same error.

Comment: com/mongodb  packages come from Mongo itself, not just the connector JAR... Why did you think you need bson? Are you following any tutorials on Mongo site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could make the mongo-kafka-connector work on Windows.

Here is what worked for me:
Kafka installation folder is E:\Tools\kafka_2.12-2.4.0

E:\Tools\kafka_2.12-2.4.0\plugins has **mongo-kafka-1.0.1-all.jar** file.

I downloaded this from https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb
Click on the blue Download button at the left to get **mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.0.1.zip** file.

There is also the file **MongoSinkConnector.properties** in the etc folder inside the zip file.
Move it to kafka_installation_folder\plugins

My **connect-standalone.propertie**s file has the following entries:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=E:/Tools/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/plugins/mongo-kafka-1.0.1-all.jar
```

My **MongoSinkConnector.properties** file has the following entries

```
name=mongo-sink
topics=topic1,topic2
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27017,localhost:27017
database=test_kafka
collection=transactions
max.num.retries=3
retries.defer.timeout=5000

field.renamer.mapping=[]
field.renamer.regex=[]

max.batch.size = 0
rate.limiting.timeout=0
rate.limiting.every.n=0
```

**How To Run**

Start mongodb, zookeeper, kafka server in three consoles.

In 4th console, start Kafka connect --

```
bin\windows\connect-standalone config\connect-standalone.properties config\MongoSinkConnector.properties
```

In 5th console, send msgs to a topic (I did for topic1)

```
bin\windows\kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic1
```

>{"Hello":1}

>{"Mongo":2}

>{"World":3}

Open a mongo client and check your database/collections. You will see these three messages.